Thinkpad P1 Gen 6 with Manjaro: Thunderbold 3 Dock and USB-C charging stopped working suddenly
I use a Belkin Thunderbold 3 Dock and it worked like a charm for nearly a year. This morning it suddenly stopped working with my Thinkpad, getting no charging and no internet connection through my Dock anymore. Any thoughts on this? I already found this in the Manjaro forums, lsmod listing usci_acpi and typec_ucsi kernel modules... Don't know what to do here.

Luckily I stumbled upon this GitHub issue and this Arch forum thread. The key is to use the boldctl command line tool. First check via boltctl list, if your Dock is connected (assuming you have your Dock physically connected via USB-C cable). This should return something (if not, there might be a hardware problem).
If your device is shown, you can try to authorize it via boltctl authorize yourDevicesUUID. For me this was already the case. If you have a problem authorizing your Thunderbold, have a look at this answer. You might have a BIOS/UEFI option incorrectly set.
If your Dock is shown, authorized but has the status disconnected, you should do a hardware reset of your power delivery system. As a Thinkpad user you can do the the reset button hole trick pressing a paper clip for 10 sec into the hole (as described in this video). Therefore power down your system and remove any cables incl. power cord. Turn your laptop to see the bottom and use the paper clip accordingly. Then power your system back on. This really did the trick for me! Thunderbold and USB-C charging now working again and boltctl list now showing this:
boltctl list
 ● Belkin International, Inc. Thunderbolt 3 Dock - Pro
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          Thunderbolt 3 Dock - Pro
   ├─ vendor:        Belkin International, Inc.
   ├─ uuid:          00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ├─ generation:    Thunderbolt 3
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     74xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   │  ├─ rx speed:   40 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 20 Gb/s
   │  ├─ tx speed:   40 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 20 Gb/s
   │  └─ authflags:  boot
   ├─ authorized:    Mon 29 Jul 2024 08:37:46 AM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Mon 29 Jul 2024 08:37:46 AM UTC
   └─ stored:        Thu 14 Mar 2024 09:12:14 AM UTC
      ├─ policy:     iommu
      └─ key:        no

